# Wifi configuraton on ubuntu 14.04 or wifi not working with ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, configuration

I'm in my universtiy and they provide WIFI privileged with a unique username and password, now I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, turned on wifi, given my username and password but I couldn't configure my wireless connection. Any Help?